# Proving a vector is an eigenvalue given an equation involving the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

i am told that v is an eigenvector of A with eigenvalue p. I am to show that p is an eigenvalue of A^3 -4A^2 + I, and find it's eigenvalue.

I have first shown that p^3 is an eigenvalue of A^3 by manipulating the equation: 
Av = pv (as v has eigenvalue p)

so i multiplied both sides by A^2, and ultimately reached the end result of:
A^3v = p^3v, and thus p^3 is an eigenvalue of A^3.

I did the same process again but instead multiplied Av = pv by A to show that p^2 is an eigenvalue of A^2.

I was wondering, will this show that v is an eigenvector of  A^3 -4A^2 + I? I have shown that p^3 is an eigenvalue of A^3 and p^2 is an eigenvalue of A^2 by playing with the Av = pv relationship.

I appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: From there, calculate $(A^3-4A^2+I)(v)$.

Comment: would this lead to it being: (p^3 - 4p^2 +I)v?

Comment: And thus,  p^3 - 4p^2 +I is the eigenvalue of v

Comment: It's not $I$ but $1$ : $p^3-4p^2+1$. So $p$ is not an eigenvalue of $A^3-4A^2+I$, but $p^3-4p^2+1$ is.